# Как удалить метку из коллекции в Яндекс.Карте?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как удалить метку из коллекции в Яндекс.Карте?

```js
var myMap,
  myPlacemark,
  myCollection;

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 7
  });

  // Отключить увеличение карты 2м кликом
  myMap.behaviors.disable('dblClickZoom');

  // Коллекция меток
  myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({}, {
    preset: 'islands#redIcon', //все метки красные
    draggable: true, // и их можно перемещать
  });

  // добавляем коллекцию на карту
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);

  // Кнопка добавления метки
  var marker_button = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {
      content: 'Добавить метку'
    }
  }, {
    selectOnClick: false
  });

  // Добавить кнопку в панель
  myMap.controls.add(marker_button);

  // При клике по кноаке, моздаем метку
  marker_button.events.add('click', function() {
    addMarker()
  });
}


function addMarker() {

  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {});

  // добавляем в коллекцию метку
  myCollection.add(myPlacemark);

  myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function(e) {
    ymaps.geoQuery(myMap.geoObjects).search('geometry.type == "Point"').each(function(pm) {
      // координаты метки
      console.log(pm.geometry.getCoordinates());
    });
  });

  // 2й клик по метке
  myPlacemark.events.add('dblclick', function(e) {
    // КАК УДАЛИТЬ?
    var thisPlacemark = e.get('target');
    myMap.geoObjects.remove(thisPlacemark);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5v53p8r/).

П.С. Чтобы добавить метку, нажмите на кнопку *"Добавить метку"* на карте в верхнем левом углу.

И еще вопрос: скопировал из примера Яндекса, но что-то не работает `selectOnClick: false`. То есть при клике на кнопку *"Добавить метку"* она остается нажатой. Как сделать так, чтобы после клика она вернулась в свое первоначальное положение?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте заменить в обработчике события объект `myMap.geoObjects` на созданную вами геоколлекцию:

```
// 2й клик по метке
myPlacemark.events.add('dblclick', function(e) {
    // КАК УДАЛИТЬ?
    var thisPlacemark = e.get('target');
    myCollection.remove(thisPlacemark);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Button-docpage/

> parameters.**options**.selectOnClick
>   true
>   Тип: Boolean

Структура параметров немного сложнее:

```
...
}, {
    options: {selectOnClick: false}
  });
...
```